# Delete one of the two app on the heroku account

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I'm new to Heroku. I've mistakenly created second app on my account and now I can't execute `heroku open` command to see my app running on the server. I'm posting the screen of the error message. I need only the one named `guarded-wildwood-67162`. How can I delete other app - `shielded-sea-53572`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [permanently destroy a Heroku app](https://kb.heroku.com/how-do-i-delete-destroy-an-app-on-heroku) you can use `heroku apps:destroy --app <app-name>` or use the Heroku web interface. Note that this doesn't just disconnect the app; it completely destroys it.